# Find and copy ranges by cells value at once

Tags: excel, vba

[Here explaining Imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znbER.jpg)
Would somebody please help me with the following.
I have an excel file with two sheets. Sheet 1, with a column containing a full list of key (id) values. A second, Sheet 2, with list of values extracted from other document that partially match with these key values, much of them are duplicated and they have information in adjancent column.
The issue.
I would like to develop a code that will find each log on Sheet 2 with its corresponding on Sheet 1 (full list), for every true, copy log found (sometimes many) with linked data in adjancent column. 
My code works, but it is too slow when i have more than 1000 logs. Im trying to find a way of selecting and/or copying by ranges of **duplicated** at once, instead going line by line.
Would you please give me a hand with this?
Many thanks!

Here as follows, my code:

```
Sub Mod2()    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim sh1, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, cfind As Range, rng1 As Range

    Set sh1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Worksheets("Insert").Activate

    Set rng = sh2.Range(sh2.Range("E10"), sh2.Range("E10").End(xlDown))
    Set rng1 = sh1.Range(sh1.Range("E15"), sh1.Range("E3000"))

    With sh1
    On Error Resume Next

        sh1.Activate
        'rng1.Select

        For Each c In rng
            Set cfind = rng1.Cells.Find(what:=c.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, after:=Range("E15"), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)            

            If Not cfind Is Nothing Then
                cfind.Offset(1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
                c.Offset(0, 1).Copy

                With cfind.Offset(0, 1)
                    .Insert shift:=xlDown
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                End With

                c.Offset(0, 10).Copy

                With cfind.Offset(0, 10)
                    .Insert shift:=xlDown
                    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                End With            
            End If
        Next c            
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: **1)** Do you need `xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats` or would pure values suffice? I am aiming at working with arrays, instead of ranges. **2)** Why are you inserting cells below `cfind`? Is it necessary? Could it be replaced by inserting whole row? Since you are again inserting cells below `cfind.offset(0,1)`.

Comment: 1- Autofilter is faster than .Find Method. 2- You could use some commands to [optimize](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm). 3- You might have to sort first and then autofilter, so you use range to range writting the values directly, it is faster than copy/paste. Otherwise you would have to make a non contiguous Range.

Comment: Entire row insert was my first option, but since i have many columns to handle, Excel was all time giving errors. Would you please share with me a sample of code with sort and autofilter? I’ll appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I would use arrays instead of ranges, since they are waaay faster.
The code below neglects inserting of the rows. It just updates the corresponding duplicate with info from ID. Takes about a blink of an eye :).

```
Public Sub updateDuplicatesWithInfoFromIDs()
    Dim IDs As Variant 'array
    Dim DuplicatesRange As Range  'we'll use this for writing after
    Dim Duplicates As Variant 'array

    Dim IndexID As Long 'inner loop index
    Dim IndexDuplicate As Long 'outer loop index
    Dim IDsUbound As Long

    IDs = Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E10"), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("N10").End(xlDown)).Value2 '10 columns, array
    Set DuplicatesRange = Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E15"), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N3000")) '10 columns, range
    Duplicates = DuplicatesRange.Value2 ' 10 columns, array

    IDsUbound = UBound(IDs) 'we need to set this only once

    For IndexDuplicate = 1 To UBound(Duplicates) 'ubound is set only once
        For IndexID = 1 To IDsUbound
            If Duplicates(IndexDuplicate, 1) = IDs(IndexID, 1) Then
                Duplicates(IndexDuplicate, 2) = IDs(IndexID, 2)
                Duplicates(IndexDuplicate, 10) = IDs(IndexID, 10)
                Exit For 'skip to next duplicate
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'We use the range to write updated values back
    DuplicatesRange.Value2 = Duplicates
End Sub
```

Also note that this will replace all the 10 columns in duplicates (with empty values in columns 3~9). That could be handled by creating multiple arrays (just the columns you need to update) and writing only those, so maybe 3 writings.

Comment: Hi again Branislav and thanks so much for this useful support. Still i have a question. The method array brings perfectly the logs, but only one of duplicates in Sheet 2. Do you know a way of bringing the duplicates (many) from Sheet 2 that coincides with found match in Sheet 1, making matching cells in Sheet 1 shift down (in blanks). My method (Insert shift:=xlDown) is really slow. I've tried with Entire.row and it fails because the amount of data. Again, thanks!

Comment: @DanielVelez Hi. Not exactly sure what you are asking. But if you want to use insert (or any other range methods) you should not use the array method in my answer. There is nothing in the array about the original range objects, just their values (hence the speed). **Solution** to that could be to convert the big arrays into collections of row arrays, and add another row arrays into collection where necesary (substituting the insert), and then convert the resulting collection of row arrays into one big final array, and write that. Complicated to explain, but sure fast to execute.

Comment: @DanielVelez the solution in my answer is maybe helpful but does not solve your problem. I would recommend to take back the *green check sign* as *accepted answer* (un-accept), so that others will know an answer is needed and can help.

Comment: @DanielVelez Hi, could you please update your question with pictures or sample data of what you have >>> what you want. You know, like "add a line below", "insert data from sheet x here", and so on.

Comment: @DanielVelez Hi. I have to admit, I will not have time to write the code for you. I am approaching a deadline, have to focus my effort there. Sorry for making you wait. How is it going anyway? Any progress?

Comment: Hi Branislav!, don't worry, your support was quite useful to me for starting. Yes, i've made some improvements, but still with find method. Hope you will meet your deadlines in time! Thanks for writing!